# Sort and show objects with True in BooleanField first

Tags: python, django, sorting

There is a class in my models, and it has `BooleanField`.
I
 want to make a sorting in which objects with `BooleanField=True` is shown first.

Is there a something for doing this in Django? I was searching through documentation but had no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Foo.objects.all().order_by('-field')
```

Like for any other field type.